# Smallest number whose sum of the digits is equal to the given number n

Tags: c++, math

Below statement gives smallest number whose sum of digit is equal to the given number n.
If the input is 10 output will be 19 (1+9=10)

```
digits=(c % 9 + 1) * pow(10, (c / 9)) - 1
```

But when the input is greater like 100000, the output shows Inf. Can anyone help me to solve this, I even tried with  `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: What is `c`? What is "the input"? The output of `pow` is obviously limited to the maximum value of `double`, so why exactly are you expecting to be able to handle any arbitrarily large input?

Comment: For `c = 100000` the number `digits` would require almost [37,000 bits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28log2%28%28%28100000+mod+9%29+%2B+1%29+*+10%5Efloor%28100000%2F9%29+-+1%29%29) to store. That's far beyond what any builtin integer type can accommodate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to print the answer and not keep it stored in an integer variable, you can avoid overflow by taking the first digit as `c%9`and append `c/9` number of `'9'` chars to complete the summation.

```
std::string getDigits(long long c)
{
    if (c == 0)
    {
        return "0";
    }

    if (c < 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    auto first = (c % 9);
    c -= first;
    auto nineCount = c / 9;

    std::string result;

    if (first != 0)
    {
        result += std::string(1, (char)(first+'0'));
    }

    result += std::string(nineCount, '9');

    return result;
}
```

Example run:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << getDigits(987) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
69999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```